# function parameter accept class type which one of it's property is type narrowing

Tags: typescript

A class has a union type property. A function accept this class with a type narrowing property. Can I define such function?

I have a login form. User need to input phone, and password or SMS code accordingly. Here is the login form class definition.

```js
export class PhoneLoginForm {
    public phone: string;
    public authForm: PhonePasswordLoginForm | PhoneSmsLoginForm;
}

export class PhonePasswordLoginForm {
    public password: string;
    public captcha: string;
}

export class PhoneSmsLoginForm {
    public sms: string;
}
```

And there is the process functions

```js
public onLogin(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm) {
    if (loginForm.authForm instanceof PhonePasswordLoginForm) {
        processPhonePasswordForm(loginForm);
    } else {
        processPhoneSmsForm(loginForm);
    }
}

// How to constrain loginForm.authForm is PhonePasswordLoginForm ?
public processPhonePasswordForm(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm) {
    // Authenticate with loginForm.phone, loginForm.authForm.password, loginForm.authForm.captcha.
}

// How to constrain loginForm.authForm is PhoneSmsLoginForm ?
public processPhoneSmsForm(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm) {
    // Authenticate with loginForm.phone, loginForm.authForm.sms.
}
```

I doesn't find this syntax in typescript document or github issue. Is it possible to define such function?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do.

First, types must be defined exactly as they are needed:

```
export type PhoneLoginForm = PhoneLoginFormWithSms | PhoneLoginFormWithPassword;

export interface PhoneLoginFormWithSms {
    phone: string;
    authForm: PhoneSmsLoginForm;
}

export interface PhoneSmsLoginForm {
    sms: string;
}

export interface PhoneLoginFormWithPassword {
    phone: string;
    authForm: PhonePasswordLoginForm;
}

export interface PhonePasswordLoginForm {
    password: string;
    captcha: string;
}
```

[Type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) can be implemented:

```
export function isPhoneLoginFormWithSms(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm): loginForm is PhoneLoginFormWithSms {
    return !!loginForm.authForm["sms"]
}

export function isPhoneLoginFormWithPassword(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm): loginForm is PhoneLoginFormWithPassword {
    return loginForm.authForm["password"] !== undefined
}
```

It is now easy to use the types:

```
function onLogin(loginForm: PhoneLoginForm) {
    if (isPhoneLoginFormWithPassword(loginForm)) {
        processPhonePasswordForm(loginForm);
    } else {
        processPhoneSmsForm(loginForm);
    }
}

function processPhonePasswordForm(loginForm: PhoneLoginFormWithPassword) {
}

function processPhoneSmsForm(loginForm: PhoneLoginFormWithSms) {
}
```

Regarding the implementation for your types, an example with classes:

```
class PhoneLoginFormWithSmsImpl implements PhoneLoginFormWithSms { 
  constructor(public phone: string, public authForm: PhoneSmsLoginForm) {
  }
}

class PhoneLoginFormWithPasswordImpl implements PhoneLoginFormWithPassword { 
  constructor(public phone: string, public authForm: PhonePasswordLoginForm) {
  }
}
```